# Scroll issue on table row removal

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code:

```
<tr id="cv643" ondblclick="onCVE(643)">
  <td colspan="2">
    <a onclick="btnCVA(41,643)" href="#">
      Actions  
      <span class="badge badgew">2</span>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>Confirm Appointment</td>
  <td>29-12-2015</td>
  <td style="color: red">12-01-2016</td>
  <td style="color: red">Pending</td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
```

Client code is:

```
function btnCVA(cpkey, cvkey) {  
  var sel, tbl;
  if (onHideCVA()) {   // test if Action list already there
    $.ajax call to create table row with id 'recCVA'
  }
}

function onHideCVA() { 
  var sel, rc=1;
  if ((sel = document.getElementById('recCVA')) !== null) {
    sel.parentNode.removeChild(sel);
    rc=0;
  }
  return rc;
}
```

When the Actions button is clicked, btnCVA creates a row underneath with the recCVA structure, the row contains a sub-table with a button on the [thead] to call onHideCVA, which removes the recCVA tr structure as such:

```
<tr id="recCVA">
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="7">
    <table id="tblCVA" class="table table-condensed">
      <thead id="Q643">
        <tr class="lpinfo">
          <th></th>
          <th>Action</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>User</th>
          <th>Recipient</th>
          <th>Due Date</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Note</th>
          <th style="text-align:right">
            <button id="addCVA" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="btnCVAA(643)">Add Action</button>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="onHideCVA()">- </button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        (Lots of trs)
    </table>
```

So there is a call to onHideCVA from btnCVA, and a straight call to onHideCVA on the inner button.
In instances where the page is larger than the screen, if I click on the button which calls onHideCVA directly, the recCVA row is removed, and the page does not scroll. Just what I want. If I click on the btnCVA a-link, onHideCVA is called indirectly, the row is removed, but the page scrolls to the top. Not what I want.
I can't figure this out. Calling onHideCVA directly removes the row and nothing. Calling onHideCVA indirectly via btnCVA removes the row but scrolls to the top of page. Very confusing.

Firefox 40.0.3.

Any help? Thanks. Eric.

Comment: where is the <a> tag? is it on the top of the table?

Comment: @PA It's within a row in a upper-level table... so it's basically <tr><td><a onclick="btnCVA(41,643)"></td>...</tr>. Each upper row will call btnCVA to add a row under that row with the recCVA structure, which is a sub-table. onHideCVA removes that created row.

Comment: please edit the question to include your html code